# Как отправить форму с html страницы на страницу которая формируется бинарным кодом

Tags: html, recaptcha, xmpp

имеется форма на сервере (https://omemo.ca:5281/register-on-omemo.ca) внешнему редактированию она не поддается, так же на ней имеется капча, которую убирать не желательно.
на другом сайте сделал красивую форму https://monolith.plus/xmpp/xmpp-register.html

name у полей продублировал (такие же как на сайте регистрации)
но при отправки формы перекидывает на страницу register-on-omemo.ca

Так же хочу заметить, брал всю форму в айфрем, вместе с капчей, в таком случае все нормально срабатывает, но так же остается не редактированный внешний вид, по этому это не подходит.

подозреваю что перекидывает на страницу из-за капчи на omemo.ca

Comment: поправьте action в форме на  monolith.plus

Comment: пробовал менять на без https:// , в таком случае ни чего не происходит